# full dualmonitor support for vnc/remote-desktop to Centos machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, multi-monitor

We have to switch over to using linux VM's, connected to from a windows box using vnc, at our office, removing existing linux development boxes that developers use to have.  We want to minimize the complaints when this transition happens, and one way of the key things to do this is to have proper dual monitor support.

I'm looking for a tool that will support dual monitors for VNC (or any other sort of remote-connection).  I know there are some hacks to get quasi-dual monitor support, but I want as close to what developers are use to getting from a physical box as possible.  Were willing to pay for licenses but obviously would prefer a free product.

One other catch, it needs to run on centos 6.9 servers (and centos 7), which some of our developers are still stuck developing on.  The clients will be windows 10 I believe.

Comment: Could you please add what OS the clients are running on, and what your price margin is when it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: @Izzy I already mentioned centos 6.9, but I've tweaked the wording to make it clearer that is refering to the client machines.  I'm afraid I don't know the price margin, I'm just the poor geeky grunt asked to research options.  Knowing my company though It can't be anything too expensive to get them to sign off on it.

Comment: By the way, it’s actually *not* obvious that you want a free-of-cost product. Some people and companies avoid such software where it means a lack of quality or support.

Comment: "I know there are some hacks to get quasi-dual monitor support" -> what hack(s) are you referring to? just curious